# Error during mongo realm function call from flutter using realm sdk

Tags: android, mongodb, flutter, realm, backend

i currently am building a flutter app and using mongo realm for authentication ,index searching as well as function call capabilities.

Everything was working fine until i ran the command: flutter upgrade, which afterwards lead to the following errors being thrown when i launch my app:

```
D/libGLESv2( 6862): STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.example.auction_app
I/flutter ( 6862): 2023-11-18T22:15:45.054885: [ERROR] Realm: HTTP Transport: Exception executing get https://us-east-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/application-0-ont/location: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
I/flutter ( 6862):      CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:393))
I/flutter ( 6862): an error has occured during retrieveAllProducts function
I/flutter ( 6862): AppException: non-zero custom status code considered fatal, status code: 999
I/flutter ( 6862): []
I/flutter ( 6862): 2023-11-18T22:15:45.240942: [ERROR] Realm: App: log_in_with_credentials failed: 0 message: non-zero custom status code considered fatal
```

i did some googling and found out about the need to add the following line to androidmanifest.xml file:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
but that didn’t fix the issue unfortunately.

i did allow access from anywhere in the realm Application settings
i did allow anonymous authentication in the app
here is the flutter code:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> retrieveAllProducts(arg) async {
    print("RetrieveAllProducts Function");
    try {
      final user = await app.logIn(emailPwCredentials);
      products = await user.functions.call('allProducts');
    } catch (e) {
      print('an error has occured during retrieveAllProducts function');
      print(e);
    }
    print(products);
    return products;
  }
```

Does anyone know any solution to such problem?
(Again everything was working fine, until i ran the command flutter upgrade )

Again i did try to add the internet permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file, expected that to fix the issue, but unfortunately it did not !